# check FLS and CRUD for more than one field

Tags: apex, fls, crud, checkmarx, security-scanner

I have a code which inserts custom Note__c object by using 5 fields. I want to check FLS and CRUD permission field level wise as they are reported in the checkmarx report.
I know we can write in if statement like this

```
if(schema.sobjectType.Note__c.fields.Message__c.isCreateable())
```

I wanted to know how can we check for more than one field instead of writing it as or condition in the IF statement. Below is my piece of code.

```
         Notes__c note= new Notes__c();  
         note.Case__c= emlist.parentid;
             IF (emlist.HTMLBody != NULL && emlist.HTMLBody != ''){
             note.Message__c = emlist.HTMLBody;
             }
             else {
             note.Message__c = emlist.TextBody;
             }    
         note.Sent_To__c = emlist.ToAddress;
         note.From__c = emlist.FromAddress;
         note.Subject__c = emlist.Subject;
         note.Datetime_Created__c = emlist.CreatedDate;
         if (emlist.Parent.Contact.Email == emlist.ToAddress || emlist.Parent.Email__c == emlist.ToAddress) // If the email is the same as Case's contact email or Email__c on Case itself, the type is a response.
         {
         note.Type__c = 'Response';
         }
         else {
         note.Type__c = 'Forward/Others';
         }
         notesList.add(note); // Add note object to the list
     }
```

Comment: Hi @AJoshi, you might also want to check the ESAPI library https://github.com/forcedotcom/force-dot-com-esapi .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of all createable fields through this way:

```
public static Set<String> getCreateableFields(Schema.SObjectType objectType) {
    Set<String> createableFields = new Set<String>();
    Map<String, Schema.SobjectField> fields = objectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for (String s : fields.keySet() ) {
        if ((s != 'Name') && (fields.get(s).getDescribe().isCreateable())) {
            createableFields.add(s.toLowerCase());
        }
    }
    return createableFields;
}
```

Then you can check in set if field exist like this:

```
Set<Schema.SobjectField> createableUserFields = getCreateableFields();
if(createableUserFields.contains(User.isactive)){}
```

Comment: @Frodo,
Can i write the code like this?

if(!(Schema.sobjecttype.case.fields.origin.iscreateable()))
        {
        }
        if(language.contains('en'))
            cseObj.Origin = 'Web - English';         
                    
        if(language.contains('es'))
            cseObj.Origin = 'Web - Spanish';
            
        if(language.contains('zh'))
            cseObj.Origin = 'Web - Chinese';
         
        if(language.contains('ja'))
            cseObj.Origin = 'Web - Japanese';

Basically do nothing if it is not createable and continue with the code

Comment: @AJoshi Rather perform logic only when user has these access. It will save else part of your logic.